# How can we make it easy to solve quadratics without the Quadratic Formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

For example ,

$$5x^2 - 7x-2=0$$

Then, we only need to find is when
$$5x^2-7x=2$$
$$x(5x-7)=2$$
Since that when we get $2-2=0$.

> Is there any way we can find them easily without solving quadratics using formula?

I am just getting very enthusiastic in this topic.

Comment: Complete the square is a way

Comment: There is [another way](https://www.poshenloh.com/quadraticdetail/), but I'm not sure why people rave about it.

Comment: You may see the latest about a quadratic equation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955267/getting-back-to-the-quadratic-equation-again

Comment: @J.G. I see no reason to rave about it. That's the standard quadratic formula, except the arithmetic calculations contained in $\frac{-b}{2a}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{-b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac ca}$ are broken down into three steps.

Comment: "Then , we only need to find is when $5x^2-7x=2.$" Yes, "only". The easiest way to do that, especially in general, is to go back to the original equation and use the quadratic formula. You may be lucky and find some $x$ that makes one factor into 1 and the other factor 2, but that's only possible if you're lucky.

Comment: The by far easiest way is to use Sridhara, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula/49243#49243.  Hence start with $100x^2-140x=40\iff 100x^2-140x+7^2=40+49\iff(10x-7)^2=89$. Now take the square root.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your strategy does not help that much because it is very difficult to solve
$$
x(5x-7)=2
$$
without simply returning to the original equation. This is because there is a $2$ on the RHS. The reason we want to be able to write a quadratic in the form
$$
(x-p)(x-q)=0
$$
is so that we can exploit the [zero-product property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-product_property): if $a \times b=0$, then $a=0$ or $b=0$. Once we have written an equation in the form $(x-p)(x-q)=0$, we can still instantly deduce that $x=p$ or $x=q$. This is something we can't do when we have something like
$$
x(5x-7)=2 \, .
$$

---

Instead, I would suggest dividing through by $5$, which yields
$$
x^2 - \frac{7}{5}x - \frac{2}{5} = 0 \, .
$$
Then, add $2/5$ to both sides:
$$
x^2 - \frac{7}{5}x = \frac{2}{5} \, \tag{*}\label{*} .
$$
The LHS is almost a perfect square. Note that
$$
\left(x-\frac{7}{10}\right)^2=x^2-\frac{7}{5}x+\frac{49}{100} \, .
$$
If we subtract $49/100$ from this equation, we get
$$
\left(x-\frac{7}{10}\right)^2-\frac{49}{100}=x^2-\frac{7}{5}x \, .
$$
Hence, the equation $\eqref{*}$ can be rewritten as
$$
\left(x-\frac{7}{10}\right)^2-\frac{49}{100}=\frac{2}{5} \, .
$$
Add $49/100$ to both sides:
$$
\left(x-\frac{7}{10}\right)^2 = \frac{2}{5}+\frac{49}{100} = \frac{89}{100} \, .
$$
Take the square root of both sides:
$$
x-\frac{7}{10} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{89}{100}} \, .
$$
Add $7/10$ to both sides:
$$
x = \frac{7}{10} \pm \sqrt{\frac{89}{100}} \, ,
$$
and we are done. This method of solving quadratics is known as [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square). Unlike factorisation, it can be used to solve any quadratic. In fact, the quadratic formula comes from completing the square on the general quadratic equation
$$
ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \, .
$$
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: "easily without solving quadratics using formula ?" Yes, deriving the quadratic formula explicitly is certainly an easy way that avoids using the quadratic formula.

Comment: @Arthur Deriving the quadratic formula by completing the square on $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is in my experience much more difficult for people to follow compared to completing the square on one particular quadratic.

Comment: But it's not easier than using the quadratic formula. And it's very debatable whether you can claim that you avoid it.

Comment: TBH it depends on the equations. I mean will you seriously use the quadratic formula for solving $x^2+x-2$? It is obvious that the roots are $1, -2$ here.

Comment: @Arthur I agree that it's not easier than using the quadratic formula. However, unless the student feels confident deriving the quadratic formula, I would prefer they use a method where they understand how it works. Of course, the quadratic formula is just completing the square. I'm not denying that. But this fact is non-obvious to someone who is actually studying quadratics.

Comment: @Mastermind817 Yes, I would suggest factorisation should be your first port of call.

Answer (score 2):

All ways of solving quadratic equations are essentially the same, but here's another tack:

You can "depress" the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ using the substitution $x=y - b/2a$.  This substitution makes the linear term disappear.  Then it's easy to solve for $y$ and then plug that answer into the substitution and recover $x$.

For your example: $ 5x^2-7x-2 =0$, let $x = y - \frac{-7}{2\cdot 5} = y+\frac{7}{10}.$  The equation becomes

$$5\left(y+\frac{7}{10}\right)^2 -7\left(y+\frac{7}{10}\right) -2=0$$

which simplifies to

$$5y^2 -\frac{89}{20}=0.$$

Solve for $y$ (which is easy because there's no linear term):

$$y^2=\frac{89}{100}$$

$$y = \pm \frac{\sqrt{89}}{10}.$$

Which means

$$x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{89}}{10} +\frac{7}{10}.$$

So all the steps are easy and obvious as long as you remember the substitution $x = y-b/2a.$

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for this brilliantly simple method! I've never known it before.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent You might be interested in the general method for solving cubic equations, then. You get rid of the $x^2$ term in $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d = 0$ by substituting $x=t-\frac{b}{3a}$.

Comment: @Joe thanks, I already knew that one, I just hadn't considered applying a similar method to quadratics.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I hadn't either, but come to think of it, it is quite an intuitive method. Notice how the vertex of a parabola is at $x=-b/(2a)$. So let $t=x+b/(2a)$. This means that when $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$, $t$ is equal to $0$. This means that the graph of the quadratic in $t$ has the vertex at $t=0$.

Comment: @Joe right, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring the equation in the form of $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ is the best way for quadratic equations if the coefficients are reasonably small (not always as in your case because the signs are different). But sometimes (if $\alpha, \beta$ turn out to have an imaginary component or the coefficients are large integers or fractions) the quadratic formula would have to be used. $$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ In your case, the quadratic formula would have to be used (or completing the square as @Joe said).

---

If you want to calculate 'intuitively', there is another method. Note that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of a quadratic of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ ; $a \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$, then $$\alpha + \beta = \frac{-b}{a}$$ and $$\alpha \beta = \frac{c}{a}$$ This can work for equations like $x^2-50x+525$ where $\alpha + \beta = -(-50) = 15+35$ and $\alpha \beta = 525 = 15*35$.

Thus it comes to mind that the roots must be $15$ and $35$ (comparing $LHS$ and $RHS$ due to which the $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ would be $(x-15)(x-35)$.

You need to practice such questions extensively to know which method is more efficient in which equation.