# Doubt in Factoring quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

I was factorising the equation $x^2 - 3x + 10$ and realised that I can do it as $x^2 -5x + 2x + 10$, since $-5x +2x = -3x$ and $5 \cdot 2 = 10$. However, this doesn't work. As we don't get the common terms in the brackets $x(x-5) + 2(x+5)$

Is this mistake because we need $-10$ instead of $10$?
That is, while checking out the multiplication of factors of $a$ and $c$, we need to make sure that it equals $ac$ along with its sign ($+$ or $-$)?

Comment: You've got it.  See [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/#vietas-formula-quadratics-easy) for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this doesn't work, but this is because you have $x-5$ in one bracket and $x+5$ in the other. Recall the distributive law, shown in this image with numbers:

[image]

Multiplying two numbers can be thought of the area of a rectangle having the numbers as side lengths. When we have rectangles of different dimensions, there is no way to combine them to make a larger rectangle with the same width or height, unless the sides have a common factor.

The same applies for variables, so that there is no way to combine a rectangle with sides $x, x-5$ and another one with sides $2, x+5$ as in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if we have another quadratic equation that could still be factorise, for example x^2 -3x+10, here 5 and 2 works. Is this because 5x2 = 10? (The signs are also correct I mean)

Comment: $5$ and $2$ do not work. If you try again with plus/minus $1$ and $10$, they do not work, so there are no solutions which are rational numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $x^2-3x-10$?

Comment: I meant $x^2 + 3x -10 $ can be written as $ x^2 - 5x +2x -10$ and this factorises. My **doubt is** is it a necessary condition as well that  factors of a.c ( here 5 and 2) should  be equal to a.c (-10) *considering* the negative/positive sign or is it just the magnitude (10) ?

Comment: $x^2 + 3x - 10$ does not factorise. You can't get anything from $x^2 - 5x + 2x - 10$.

Comment: It's + 5x - 2x sorry! Then it does factorise. Is I
This because there is a condition that -5•2 = -10 or we just need the magnitude?

Answer (score 0):

It works but you can no more guess. So or the roots of $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-B\pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$

Also see:
[Getting back to the quadratic equation again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955267/getting-back-to-the-quadratic-equation-again)